# Custom DRF list function not returning some of the dict key/value pairs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to replace the standard list function inside a Django REST Framework viewset with a custom one, but am losing the count, previous, next params. With no override, a list function returns the following:

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [...]
}
```

Whereas when I override the function, I only get the results list, not the higher-level dict with count, next, previous, etc.

What part of the function below is missing from here that would enable that functionality?

```
def list(self, request):
    loc = Location.objects.filter(user=request.user).latest('timestamp')
    nearby = loc.get_near()  # returns a list with dicts that contain user and dist

    nearby_users = [n['user'] for n in nearby]  # gets a list of users

    serializer = self.get_serializer(nearby_users, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add pagination

```
def list(self, request):
    loc = Location.objects.filter(user=request.user).latest('timestamp')
    nearby = loc.get_near()  # returns a list with dicts that contain user and dist

    nearby_users = [n['user'] for n in nearby]  # gets a list of users

    # start pagination
    page = self.paginate_queryset(nearby_users)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    # end pagination

    serializer = self.get_serializer(nearby_users, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

more details in super [mixins](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py) from line 39

Comment: glad to help you!